# most frequent occurence

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with transactions and a statement that is giving out the most used creditcards. AMEX, VISA ...

```
SELECT CARDBRAND,
   count(*) as cardused
from INFO c
left join paytb t
   on c.CONT_ID = t.CONT_ID
GROUP BY CARDBRAND
ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

Now I want to add a column with the MERCHNAME of the shops that were most often found in a transaction with the creditcard:

```
CARDBRAND    CARDUSED        MERCHNAME
----------------------------------------
AMEX          182345         Gasstation 
VISA           70943          ....
```

Comment: please show schema of table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CARDBRAND
  ,count(*) as cardused
  ,MERCHNAME
FROM INFO c
LEFT JOIN paytb t
    on c.CONT_ID = t.CONT_ID
GROUP BY CARDBRAND,
         MERCHNAME
ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```

suggestion: It is always recommended to use the ColumnName or function in this case in the ORDERBY clause rather than the column number to avoid any confusion.

Comment: This is giving out all the merchnames with the most used card. I would like to have all the cardbrands with the most visited shop.

Comment: @bastel could you provide the schema in your question so that your question is more clear?

Answer (score 0):

First, your correct query should be:

```
select c.cardbrand, count(t.cont_id) as cardused
from info c left join
     paytb t
     on c.cont_id = t.cont_id
group by c.cardbrand;
```

Otherwise, you will never get "0" for card brands that are not used.

For the merchant information, you can use window functions:

```
select cardbrand, total_cardused, merchant
from (select c.cardbrand, t.merchant, count(t.cont_id) as cardused,
             sum(count(t.cont_id)) over (partition by c.cardbrand) as total_cardused,
             row_number() over (partition by c.cardbrand order by count(t.cont_id) desc) as seqnum
      from info c left join
           paytb t
           on c.cont_id = t.cont_id
      group by c.cardbrand, t.merchant
     ) cm
where seqnum = 1
group by c.cardbrand;
```

Comment: It says SQLCODE = -206, ERROR:  C.CARDBRAND IS NOT VALID IN
THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED